# Why does sklearn Pipeline call transform() so many more times than fit()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

After a lot of reading and inspecting the pipeline.fit() operation under different `verbose` param settings, I'm still confused why a pipeline of mine visits a certain step's `transform` method so many times.

Below is a trivial example `pipeline`, `fit` with `GridSearchCV`, using 3-fold cross-validation, but a param-grid with only one set of hyperparams. So I expected three runs through the pipeline. Both `step1` and `step2` have `fit` called three times, as expected, but each step has `transform` called several more times. Why is this? Minimal code example and log output below.

```
# library imports
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Load toy data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)
y = pd.Series(iris.target, name='y')

# Define a couple trivial pipeline steps
class mult_everything_by(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, multiplier=2):
        self.multiplier = multiplier

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print "Fitting step 1"
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print "Transforming step 1"
        return X* self.multiplier

class do_nothing(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, meaningless_param = 'hello'):
        self.meaningless_param=meaningless_param


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print "Fitting step 2"
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print "Transforming step 2"
        return X

# Define the steps in our Pipeline
pipeline_steps = [('step1', mult_everything_by()),
                  ('step2', do_nothing()), 
                  ('classifier', LogisticRegression()),
                  ]

pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline_steps)

# To keep this example super minimal, this param grid only has one set
# of hyperparams, so we are only fitting one type of model
param_grid = {'step1__multiplier': [2],   #,3],
              'step2__meaningless_param': ['hello']   #, 'howdy', 'goodbye']
              }

# Define model-search process/object
# (fit one model, 3-fits due to 3-fold cross-validation)
cv_model_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, 
                               param_grid, 
                               cv = KFold(3),
                               refit=False, 
                               verbose = 0) 

# Fit all (1) models defined in our model-search object
cv_model_search.fit(X,y)
```

Output:

```
Fitting step 1
Transforming step 1
Fitting step 2
Transforming step 2
Transforming step 1
Transforming step 2
Transforming step 1
Transforming step 2
Fitting step 1
Transforming step 1
Fitting step 2
Transforming step 2
Transforming step 1
Transforming step 2
Transforming step 1
Transforming step 2
Fitting step 1
Transforming step 1
Fitting step 2
Transforming step 2
Transforming step 1
Transforming step 2
Transforming step 1
Transforming step 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have used `GridSearchCV` with `cv = KFold(3)` which will do a cross-validation of your model. Here's what happens:

1. It will split the data into two parts: train and test.
2. For train, it will fit and transform each part of pipeline (excluding last, which is the classifier). Thats why you are seeing `fit step1, transform step1, fit step2, transform step2`.
3. It will fit the transformed data on the classifier (which is not printed in your output.
4. **Edited** Now comes the scoring part. Here we dont want to re-fit the parts again. We will use the information learnt during previous fitting. So each part of the pipeline will only call transform(). Thats the reason for `Transforming step 1, Transforming step 2`.

   Its showing two times because in GridSearchCV, default behaviour is to compute the score of both training and testing data. This behaviour is geverned by `return_train_score`. You can set `return_train_score=False` and will only see them once.
5. This transformed test data will be used to predict the output from the classifier. (Again, no fitting on test, only predicting or transforming).
6. The predicted values will be used to compare with the actual values to score the model.
7. The steps 1-6 will be repeated 3 times `(KFold(3))`.
8. Now have a look at your params:

   param_grid = {'step1__multiplier': [2],   #,3],
                 'step2__meaningless_param': ['hello']   #, 'howdy', 'goodbye']
                 }

   When expanding, it becomes only single combination i.e.:

   **Combination1**: 'step1__multiplier'=2, 'step2__meaningless_param' = 'hello'

   If you have provided more options, which you have commented more combinations would be possible like:

   **Combination1**: 'step1__multiplier'=2, 'step2__meaningless_param' = 'hello'

   **Combination2**: 'step1__multiplier'=3, 'step2__meaningless_param' = 'hello'

   **Combination3**: 'step1__multiplier'=2, 'step2__meaningless_param' = 'howdy'

   and so on..
9. The steps 1-7 will be repeated for each possible combination.
10. The combination which gave highest average score on the test folds of the cross-validation will be chosen to finally fit the model with complete data (no division into train and test).
11. But you have kept `refit=False` . So the model will not be fitted again. Else you would have seen one more output of

    Fitting step 1
    Transforming step 1
    Fitting step 2
    Transforming step 2

Hope this clears this up. Feel free to ask any more info.

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks a lot for your answer. I still don't quite see how it explains my log output. Your point 2 explains how I get to `fit step1, transform step1, fit step2, transform step2`. I'm with you so far. Your point 4. was very helpful, I hadn't thought of that, so that explains the next `Transforming step 1, Transforming step 2`. But we still have on more `Transforming step 1, Transforming step 2` to explain before we get back to the second KFold - where my log starts over again at line 9 with the second instance of `Fitting step 1`. How do we explain those lines 7&8 in my log output?

Comment: @MaxPower Aah yes. I overlooked that, sorry. Thats because the GridSearchCV will also keep a recored of scores on training data. So it will again score the model based on training data, hence the repeated steps, once for testing and once for training. I will update the answer in a short while with an example. You can look at [`GridSearchCV.cv_results_`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) attribute to check what metrics it keeps.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. With the `return_train_score` elaboration, that accounts for all the printed steps. So that's how it works. But are those last two `transform`s for `return_train_score` really required? As you point out in your point 2., "for train...[we have] `fit step1`, `transform step1`, `fit step2`, `transform step2`". And then the pipeline "fits the transformed data on the classifier" (your 3.). At that point we already have everything we need to produce `train_score`: our fitted classifier will .predict() us train-preds. And we have train_y given. So why the extra transform steps later?

Comment: @MaxPower Yes, thats what I was thinking. Thats just repeating the same steps, which is time-consuming. I think you should post this as an issue to the [scikit-learn github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues). This maybe an enhancement that they are already working on (I have read that they are working on caches for pipeline to reuse parts of data later, but not sure about this)  and you will get to know about.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, will do, though probably not til this weekend. Yeah I also read up a bit on `Pipeline`'s memory param for caching transformers but I don't think that addresses this issue. I could be misunderstanding it though.

Comment: issue filed here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10090

Comment: answer from core dev jnothman: `"Yes it does, and I don't think avoiding it will be easy nor worthwhile..."`

Comment: @MaxPower Yes. I was also thinking along the same lines. Currently they are overwhelmed with the other issues which in their opinion are more important. Thanks for notifying me about this. :)

Comment: Yeah I'd certainly never argue with a library dev about prioritization. Just glad I know at least why the steps happen each time now. Thanks again for the answer and follow up vivek