# Cross-validation of a stack of classifiers without data shuffle returns garbage

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

As a follow-up to [How to compose sklearn estimators using another estimator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53545549/850781),
I am trying to cross-validate a stack of models.

## Manual

First I do all the steps manually to make sure everything works as intended:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=40,
                           n_clusters_per_class=10,
                           n_informative=25,
                           random_state=12, shuffle=False)

logit = LogisticRegression(solver="saga",random_state=12).fit(X,y)
logit_yhat = logit.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
print("logit",roc_auc_score(y, logit_yhat))
randf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,max_depth=5,min_samples_split=10, random_state=12).fit(X,y)
randf_yhat = randf.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
print("randf",roc_auc_score(y, randf_yhat))
gaunb = GaussianNB().fit(X,y)
gaunb_yhat = gaunb.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
print("gaunb",roc_auc_score(y, gaunb_yhat))
gbcdt = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=12).fit(X,y)
gbcdt_yhat = gbcdt.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
print("gbcdt",roc_auc_score(y, gbcdt_yhat))

scores = np.transpose(np.array((logit_yhat, randf_yhat, gaunb_yhat, gbcdt_yhat)))
aggregator = LogisticRegression(solver="saga",random_state=12).fit(scores, y)
aggregator_yhat = aggregator.predict_proba(scores)[:,1]
print("aggregator",aggregator.coef_,roc_auc_score(y, aggregator_yhat))
```

This prints:

```
logit 0.6913163859713081
randf 0.7871255096874669
gaunb 0.7032834038916749
gbcdt 0.8527915275109933
aggregator [[-3.95961856  5.70858186 -2.45036885 13.3983472 ]] 0.8799606190093959
```

So far so good.

## Using pipelines

Now I create a pipeline and check that it does the same thing:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, clone
class PredictProbaTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, clf):
        self.clf = clf

    def transform(self, X):
        "Return predict_proba(X)."
        print("transform")
        return self.clf.predict_proba(X)[:,[1]]

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        print("fit_transform")
        return self.clf.fit(X, y, **fit_params).predict_proba(X)[:,[1]]

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
pipe = Pipeline([("stack",FeatureUnion([
    ("logit",PredictProbaTransformer(clone(logit))),
    ("randf",PredictProbaTransformer(clone(randf))),
    ("gaunb",PredictProbaTransformer(clone(gaunb))),
    ("gbcdt",PredictProbaTransformer(clone(gbcdt))),
])), ("aggregator",LogisticRegression(solver="saga",random_state=12))]).fit(X,y)
pipe_yhat = pipe.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
print("pipe",pipe.named_steps["aggregator"].coef_,roc_auc_score(y, pipe_yhat))
```

This prints:

```
pipe [[-3.95961856  5.70858186 -2.45036885 13.3983472 ]] 0.8799606190093959
```

Identical to the `aggregator` line in the "manual" section - good!

## Cross-validation

When I try to cross-validate the `pipe`, I get some weirdness:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
pipe_scores = pd.DataFrame(cross_validate(
    pipe, X=X, y=y, return_train_score=True, cv=10, scoring="roc_auc"))
```

Prints 10 times (because `cv=10`) these 12 lines:

```
fit_transform --- 4 times
transform     --- 8 times
```

Because it calls `fit_transform` 4 times for the 4 classifiers in `stack` for each training phase), and then calls `transform` 4 times for the same 4 classifiers in the *test* data, and then [***again***](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10090) 4 more times on the train data (even though it already did it in the train phase).

**Most important**: `pipe_scores.describe()` is

```
        fit_time  score_time  test_score  train_score
count  10.000000   10.000000   10.000000    10.000000
mean    3.329516    0.006074    0.482034     0.895046
std     0.068609    0.000594    0.081499     0.006657
min     3.212703    0.005362    0.299673     0.886333
25%     3.276795    0.005602    0.451310     0.891166
50%     3.350762    0.006122    0.504630     0.892991
75%     3.370433    0.006331    0.519399     0.898570
max     3.425937    0.007302    0.586310     0.906820
```

Weirdly enough, *all* `train_score`s are above the 88% I got in my
manual run.

However, ***why do the `test_score`s appear to be completely random?!***
(mean and median are around 50%, corresponding to a "coin toss" classifier).

The **workaround** to avoid this weirdness is to ***shuffle rows*** by

- *either* passing `shuffle=True` (instead of `False`) to [`make_classification`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html)
- *or* passing [`cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,shuffle=True,random_state=12)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) (instead of `10`) to [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html).

Then the scores are

```
        fit_time  score_time  test_score  train_score
count  10.000000   10.000000   10.000000    10.000000
mean    3.400829    0.005355    0.774932     0.887762
std     0.125579    0.000444    0.011324     0.003578
min     3.211147    0.004896    0.763047     0.883219
25%     3.333121    0.005074    0.767166     0.884810
50%     3.376660    0.005153    0.772864     0.886907
75%     3.484209    0.005516    0.781219     0.890338
max     3.602676    0.006194    0.799907     0.893941
```

PS. `shuffle` in [`make_classification`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) affects *both* columns *and* rows while in [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) it affects only *rows*, not *columns*.
Only **row** shuffle matters: if I shuffle columns by

```
X = X[:, np.random.permutation(X.shape[1])]
```

after [`make_classification(... shuffle=False)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html), I get identical [`GaussianNB`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html) and [`GradientBoostingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) and imperceptibly different [`LogisticRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), and the [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) returns *random* `test_scores`.

Comment: As for why it prints transform `8 times`, see [my answer here and specifically the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47066401/3374996). And for test scores, in all the above examples (without cross-validation) you are training and scoring on the same data (`X`, `y`). In cross-validation train and test data are different. Try using different train test data for your upper codes. Maybe try tuning the hyper-params

Comment: @VivekKumar: thanks for the link. When I call `KFold` manually, I get the same results, I don't think your explanation of `test_score`s holds water (but I might be misunderstanding you).

Comment: I am not sure about `"When I call KFold manually, I get the same results"`. Do you get same results (around 88 %) on test folds also? Can you show that code?

Comment: @VivekKumar: Yes, the same results for both `test` and `train` from `for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y): ...` as in `cross_validate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why all `train_scores` are above 88%, this is due to the fact that when cross-validating you train on 0.9 of your training data. Thus your models can (over)fit better on this data. As to why `test_score` is so small when you don't shuffle features, I believe this happens because when cross validating without shuffle not all (of 10) clusters are present in training dataset (which is 0.9 of all data) as in the dataset they are also not shuffled.

Comment: `train_scores` sounds plausible, `test_score` not so much - they are completely _random_. How does shuffling affect the behavior so overwhelmingly?!

Comment: That's because `shuffle` relates to shuffling features not samples in `make_classification`. That's why it may have such a huge impact. Models such as `RandomForestClassifier`  and `GradientBoostingClassifier` are very sensitive to features' order.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the answer. `GradientBoostingClassifier` actually tries to choose best possible split and so doesn't depend on their order.

Comment: Indeed, reducing `n_clusters_per_class` and increasing `cv` results in sensible `test_score `. Thanks!